# Support if-else ios 15 or lower than ios 15

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios15

I have specific line of code which only execute if ios version is lower than 15.

I could if-else if ios is great 15 by these.

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {} else {}
```

I would to do opposite of it. If ios version is lower than 15 then execute specfic line of code. I know I can write code in else part and it should have work but looking for more ideas and faster way for app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For older versions of Swift, that's exactly how you do it.

Swift 5.6 (i.e. Xcode 13.3 or newer) added the condition you're asking for, as `#unavailable`, so you can now do this:

```
if #unavailable(iOS 15.0) {
    // only runs if <iOS 15
}
```

All the details are here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0290-negative-availability.md

Comment: You gave the right approact but its giving error for me.

Comment: Error - "Platform wildcard '*' is always implicit in #unavailable"

Comment: Oops, my bad, you don't put the wildcard in. I edited my answer so that it works.

Comment: so doing like this.                 if #unavailable(iOS 15.0) {}

Comment: Will it support in ios 16. Im sure it wont exectute block of code for ios 15

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but `#unavailable(iOS 15)` will only execute on iOS versions OLDER than 15, so it will also exclude iOS 16.